# BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length ( 'name' NOT PIMARY WTF )

Tags: mysql, datatables, phpmyadmin

I'm sorry, but i don't understend that happened. So.

```
CREATE TABLE carsindrive (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `year` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `car_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(`name`) REFERENCES `cars`(`name`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`year`) REFERENCES `cars`(`year`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`car_color`) REFERENCES `cars`(`car_color`)   
);
```

Why i have this error?

#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic restrictions, You can see here

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

"Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. Consequently, BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length."